# Replace a int or long with a string in for loop?

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I needed to print the Fibonacci Sequence up to 50 numbers, which I eventually figured out, but I also need to replace certain numbers that are divisible by some number with certain words. I kind of figured this out. I got the words to come up, but I could not replace the number. I tried using String.valueOf and replaceAll, but the number still keeps showing up. I left that part of the code in comments because it was not working. I am going to post my code below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long n = 50;
    System.out.print("1 ");
    long x = 0;
    long y = 1;

    String mult3 = "cheese";
    String mult5 = "cake";
    String mult7 = "factory";
    String mult2 = "blah";

    for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        long forSum = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = forSum;

        if(forSum==89){
            System.out.println("");
        }
        if(forSum==10946){
            System.out.println("");
        }
        if(forSum==1346269){
            System.out.println("");
        }
        if(forSum==165580141){
            System.out.println("");
        }

        if(forSum %3 == 0){
            //String mult3 = String.valueOf(forSum); 
            //String mult4 = "cheese";
            //String mult3cheese = mult3.replaceAll(mult3, mult4);
            //System.out.print(mult3cheese);
            System.out.print(mult3);
        }
        if(forSum %5 == 0){
            System.out.print(mult5);
        }
        if(forSum %7 == 0){
            System.out.print(mult7);
        }

        if(forSum %2 == 0){
            System.out.print(mult2);
        }
        System.out.print(forSum + " ");
    }//for loop for forSum
}//public static void main
```

Comment: String.valueOf, Integer.toString, or just (num + "") will all convert to a String. What exactly isn't working? What's the intended behavior and what is the actual output?

Comment: oh, this is just the famous fizz buzz problem... millions of solutions available online.

Comment: @Renato wow, I didn't even realize that. That makes this much easier, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place some "continue" statements to skip past the line that prints the number, if you have matched a "replace the number" condition:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
long n = 50;
System.out.print("1 ");
long x = 0;
long y = 1;

String mult3 = "cheese";
String mult5 = "cake";
String mult7 = "factory";
String mult2 = "blah";

for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    long forSum = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = forSum;

    if(forSum==89){
        continue;
    }
    if(forSum==10946){
        continue;
    }
    if(forSum==1346269){
        continue;
    }
    if(forSum==165580141){
        continue;
    }

    if(forSum %3 == 0){
        //String mult3 = String.valueOf(forSum); 
        //String mult4 = "cheese";
        //String mult3cheese = mult3.replaceAll(mult3, mult4);
        //System.out.print(mult3cheese);
        System.out.print(mult3 + " ");
        continue
    }
    if(forSum %5 == 0){
        System.out.print(mult5 + " ");
        continue;
    }
    if(forSum %7 == 0){
        System.out.print(mult7 + " ");
        continue;
    }

    if(forSum %2 == 0){
        System.out.print(mult2 + " ");
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print(forSum + " ");
  }//for loop for forSum
}//public static void main
```

"continue" means "skip the rest of the code inside this loop and do the next iteration of the loop"